# UNION ALL does not apply on multiple seperate queries into 6 different databases

Tags: sql, sql-server

My goal is to insert the results of the 6 individual scripts into a table, it is separated into 6 because it uses  different Databases. I used UNION ALL to combine all results and insert into a newly created table. I have done this before and it became successful. Below is the example that I have done this successfully before.

```
INSERT INTO ResourceTask.dbo.DimEntity

SELECT e.EntCode, 
       e.Name, 
       e.Active, 
       e.AccessLevel, 
       ss.SiteURN, 
       ss.CompanyURN,
       ss.SiteName, 
       ss.SiteDesc, 
       ss.SiteURL
  FROM SEC_A.dbo.SECSite ss, SEC_A.dbo.SECLegalEnt e
 WHERE ss.localsiteflag = 1
   AND e.active = 1

 UNION ALL

SELECT e.EntCode, 
       e.Name, 
       e.Active, 
       e.AccessLevel, 
       ss.SiteURN, 
       ss.CompanyURN,
       ss.SiteName, 
       ss.SiteDesc, 
       ss.SiteURL
  FROM SEC_B.dbo.SECSite ss, SEC_B.dbo.SECLegalEnt e
 WHERE ss.localsiteflag = 1
   AND e.active = 1

 UNION ALL

SELECT e.EntCode, 
       e.Name, 
       e.Active, 
       e.AccessLevel, 
       ss.SiteURN, 
       ss.CompanyURN,
       ss.SiteName, 
       ss.SiteDesc, 
       ss.SiteURL
  FROM SEC_C.dbo.SECSite ss, SEC_C.dbo.SECLegalEnt e
 WHERE ss.localsiteflag = 1
   AND e.active = 1

UNION ALL

SELECT e.EntCode, 
       e.Name, 
       e.Active, 
       e.AccessLevel, 
       ss.SiteURN, 
       ss.CompanyURN,
       ss.SiteName, 
       ss.SiteDesc, 
       ss.SiteURL
  FROM SEC_D.dbo.SECSite ss, SEC_D.dbo.SECLegalEnt e
 WHERE ss.localsiteflag = 1
   AND e.active = 1

 UNION ALL

SELECT e.EntCode, 
       e.Name, 
       e.Active, 
       e.AccessLevel, 
       ss.SiteURN, 
       ss.CompanyURN,
       ss.SiteName, 
       ss.SiteDesc, 
       ss.SiteURL
  FROM SEC_E.dbo.SECSite ss, SEC_E.dbo.SECLegalEnt e
 WHERE ss.localsiteflag = 1
   AND e.active = 1
```

Below is the actual script that I am having errors.

When I use UNION ALL for repeated scripts under SEC_A to SEC_F database I get the following error message. I have tried running all individual scripts and it works. But when I apply UNION ALL. It gives me the error message.

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 31
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'UNION'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 32
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'UNION'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 32
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'UNION'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 32
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'UNION'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 32
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'UNION'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 32
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'UNION'.
```

This it the actual script that I use which gets the errors on top.

```
use SEC_A
go
select CONVERT(int,CAST(BusinessEntityID AS varchar(20)) + CAST(ContactID AS varchar(20))) as ContactID,
  'SEC_A' as SiteID,
  Clientname, 
  Contact_FirstName, 
  Contact_LastName ,
  Position,
  Phone,
  MobilePhone,
  EmailAdress
from (  
  select distinct e.BusinessEntityID,
    e.ContactID,
    d.SoldToShortName as Clientname, 
    e.FirstName as Contact_FirstName, 
    e.LastName as Contact_LastName ,
    e.Position,
    e.Phone,
    e.MobilePhone,
    e.EmailAddr as EmailAdress

  from projectrule d
  left join BusinessEntityAssociation BEA 
  on d.soldtoID = BEA.customerID 
  left join BusinessEntityContact e 
  on e.BusinessEntityID = BEA.BusinessEntityID 

  where d.SoldToShortName IS NOT NULL
     and e.BusinessEntityID is not null
     ) A order by Clientname,ContactID

UNION ALL

use SEC_B
go
select CONVERT(int,CAST(BusinessEntityID AS varchar(20)) + CAST(ContactID AS varchar(20))) as ContactID,
  'SEC_B' as SiteID,
  Clientname, 
  Contact_FirstName, 
  Contact_LastName ,
  Position,
  Phone,
  MobilePhone,
  EmailAdress
from (  
  select distinct e.BusinessEntityID,
    e.ContactID,
    d.SoldToShortName as Clientname, 
    e.FirstName as Contact_FirstName, 
    e.LastName as Contact_LastName ,
    e.Position,
    e.Phone,
    e.MobilePhone,
    e.EmailAddr as EmailAdress

  from projectrule d
  left join BusinessEntityAssociation BEA 
  on d.soldtoID = BEA.customerID 
  left join BusinessEntityContact e 
  on e.BusinessEntityID = BEA.BusinessEntityID 

  where d.SoldToShortName IS NOT NULL
     and e.BusinessEntityID is not null
     ) A order by Clientname,ContactID


UNION ALL

use SEC_C 
go
select CONVERT(int,CAST(BusinessEntityID AS varchar(20)) + CAST(ContactID AS varchar(20))) as ContactID,
  'SEC_C' as SiteID,
  Clientname, 
  Contact_FirstName, 
  Contact_LastName ,
  Position,
  Phone,
  MobilePhone,
  EmailAdress
from (  
  select distinct e.BusinessEntityID,
    e.ContactID,
    d.SoldToShortName as Clientname, 
    e.FirstName as Contact_FirstName, 
    e.LastName as Contact_LastName ,
    e.Position,
    e.Phone,
    e.MobilePhone,
    e.EmailAddr as EmailAdress

  from projectrule d
  left join BusinessEntityAssociation BEA 
  on d.soldtoID = BEA.customerID 
  left join BusinessEntityContact e 
  on e.BusinessEntityID = BEA.BusinessEntityID 

  where d.SoldToShortName IS NOT NULL
     and e.BusinessEntityID is not null
     ) A order by Clientname,ContactID


     UNION ALL

use SEC_D 
go
select CONVERT(int,CAST(BusinessEntityID AS varchar(20)) + CAST(ContactID AS varchar(20))) as ContactID,
  'SEC_D' as SiteID,
  Clientname, 
  Contact_FirstName, 
  Contact_LastName ,
  Position,
  Phone,
  MobilePhone,
  EmailAdress
from (  
  select distinct e.BusinessEntityID,
    e.ContactID,
    d.SoldToShortName as Clientname, 
    e.FirstName as Contact_FirstName, 
    e.LastName as Contact_LastName ,
    e.Position,
    e.Phone,
    e.MobilePhone,
    e.EmailAddr as EmailAdress

  from projectrule d
  left join BusinessEntityAssociation BEA 
  on d.soldtoID = BEA.customerID 
  left join BusinessEntityContact e 
  on e.BusinessEntityID = BEA.BusinessEntityID 

  where d.SoldToShortName IS NOT NULL
     and e.BusinessEntityID is not null
     ) A order by Clientname,ContactID


  UNION ALL

use SEC_E  
go
select CONVERT(int,CAST(BusinessEntityID AS varchar(20)) + CAST(ContactID AS varchar(20))) as ContactID,
  'SEC_E' as SiteID,
  Clientname, 
  Contact_FirstName, 
  Contact_LastName ,
  Position,
  Phone,
  MobilePhone,
  EmailAdress
from (  
  select distinct e.BusinessEntityID,
    e.ContactID,
    d.SoldToShortName as Clientname, 
    e.FirstName as Contact_FirstName, 
    e.LastName as Contact_LastName ,
    e.Position,
    e.Phone,
    e.MobilePhone,
    e.EmailAddr as EmailAdress

  from projectrule d
  left join BusinessEntityAssociation BEA 
  on d.soldtoID = BEA.customerID 
  left join BusinessEntityContact e 
  on e.BusinessEntityID = BEA.BusinessEntityID 

  where d.SoldToShortName IS NOT NULL
     and e.BusinessEntityID is not null
     ) A order by Clientname,ContactID


    UNION ALL

use SEC_F    
go
select CONVERT(int,CAST(BusinessEntityID AS varchar(20)) + CAST(ContactID AS varchar(20))) as ContactID,
  'SEC_F' as SiteID,
  Clientname, 
  Contact_FirstName, 
  Contact_LastName ,
  Position,
  Phone,
  MobilePhone,
  EmailAdress
from (  
  select distinct e.BusinessEntityID,
    e.ContactID,
    d.SoldToShortName as Clientname, 
    e.FirstName as Contact_FirstName, 
    e.LastName as Contact_LastName ,
    e.Position,
    e.Phone,
    e.MobilePhone,
    e.EmailAddr as EmailAdress

  from projectrule d
  left join BusinessEntityAssociation BEA 
  on d.soldtoID = BEA.customerID 
  left join BusinessEntityContact e 
  on e.BusinessEntityID = BEA.BusinessEntityID 

  where d.SoldToShortName IS NOT NULL
     and e.BusinessEntityID is not null
     ) A order by Clientname,ContactID
```

Can someone help me with this? Thank you.

I have attempted to Remove ContactID from **order by Clientname,ContactID**
but it still doesnt work. SO i decided to remove the whole **order by Clientname,ContactID** 
and I get the error message below.

[image]

I think I have found the answer. Correct me if am wrong or if you have a better Idea, I am more than willing to learn from you guys. I have put the database name before the tables. Example: SEC_B.dbo.table

```
select CONVERT(int,CAST(BusinessEntityID AS varchar(20)) + CAST(ContactID AS varchar(20))) as ContactID,
  'SEC_A' as SiteID,
  Clientname, 
  Contact_FirstName, 
  Contact_LastName ,
  Position,
  Phone,
  MobilePhone,
  EmailAdress
from (  
  select distinct e.BusinessEntityID,
    e.ContactID,
    d.SoldToShortName as Clientname, 
    e.FirstName as Contact_FirstName, 
    e.LastName as Contact_LastName ,
    e.Position,
    e.Phone,
    e.MobilePhone,
    e.EmailAddr as EmailAdress

  from SEC_A.dbo.projectrule d
  left join SEC_A.dbo.BusinessEntityAssociation BEA 
  on d.soldtoID = BEA.customerID 
  left join SEC_A.dbo.BusinessEntityContact e 
  on e.BusinessEntityID = BEA.BusinessEntityID 

  where d.SoldToShortName IS NOT NULL
     and e.BusinessEntityID is not null
     ) A --order by Clientname

UNION ALL


select CONVERT(int,CAST(BusinessEntityID AS varchar(20)) + CAST(ContactID AS varchar(20))) as ContactID,
  'SEC_B' as SiteID,
  Clientname, 
  Contact_FirstName, 
  Contact_LastName ,
  Position,
  Phone,
  MobilePhone,
  EmailAdress
from (  
  select distinct e.BusinessEntityID,
    e.ContactID,
    d.SoldToShortName as Clientname, 
    e.FirstName as Contact_FirstName, 
    e.LastName as Contact_LastName ,
    e.Position,
    e.Phone,
    e.MobilePhone,
    e.EmailAddr as EmailAdress

  from SEC_B.dbo.projectrule d
  left join SEC_B.dbo.BusinessEntityAssociation BEA 
  on d.soldtoID = BEA.customerID 
  left join SEC_B.dbo.BusinessEntityContact e 
  on e.BusinessEntityID = BEA.BusinessEntityID 

  where d.SoldToShortName IS NOT NULL
     and e.BusinessEntityID is not null
     ) A --order by Clientname
```

Comment: Enclosed with parentheses all the select and try

Comment: Your script also has several `use SEC_C ` and `go`, all over the place. Is this the actual script or there was a problem when posting here?

Comment: `GO` is a batch terminator.. You can't create a sql script that covers several batches.

Comment: Thank You NickyvV for telling me the use of GO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the `order by Clientname,ContactID` in the unioned subqueries. Remove those.

A union can only have one `ORDER BY`, at the end.

And if these `USE` and `GO` between the subqueries mean that you want to use different databases, then it's not allowed either. `GO` is a batch separator and `USE` is an TSQL statement, you can't just throw them in the middle of a SQL statement or query.

You should rewrite:

```
select CONVERT(...
...

  from SEC_A.dbo.projectrule d
  left join SEC_A.dbo.BusinessEntityAssociation BEA 
  on d.soldtoID = BEA.customerID 
  left join SEC_A.dbo.BusinessEntityContact e 
  on e.BusinessEntityID = BEA.BusinessEntityID 

  where d.SoldToShortName IS NOT NULL
     and e.BusinessEntityID is not null
     ) A
  -- ORDER BY removed

-- USE removed
-- GO removed

UNION ALL

select CONVERT(...
...  

...

UNION ALL

select CONVERT(...
...

  from SEC_E.dbo.projectrule d
  left join SEC_E.dbo.BusinessEntityAssociation BEA 
  on d.soldtoID = BEA.customerID 
  left join SEC_E.dbo.BusinessEntityContact e 
  on e.BusinessEntityID = BEA.BusinessEntityID 

-- and the (only one) ORDER BY here
ORDER BY Clientname,ContactID ;
```